# Edit with no Edit Summary

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, suggested-edits, edit-summary

I am surprised to find the following bug in edit system:

Follow the steps bellow:

1. A user with reputation **less** than 2000 points edits a post.
2. Instead of a edit summary message he insert this: `" "` (one space) and he receive a message that he has to enter a 10 chars longer message. He insert more than `ten spaces` inside of Edit Summary textbox, and click Save Edits button.
3. When a user with reputation **higher** than 2000 reviews this edit the result is this:

> [image]

Do you see? No edit summary at above screen shot.

For another example of the issue, take a look at [rev 4 in the history of this very question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/167725/revisions).

Instead of using `if (... .length > 10)`, shouldn't be used `if (... .trim().length > 10)`?

Comment: SE is build on top of .NET/C#...so those function and property names should be UpperCamelCase (`.Trim()`)...just saying...

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby, the important thing is the idea. I wrote in Javascript because I think that there is a client side.

Comment: @John good idea just did it with 10 spaces, take a look at update in rev 4 :)

Comment: @gnat, You've just edited my question with no edit summary message. :-)

Comment: @gnat since you've got the rep to edit, you're not required to enter a summary anyway.

Comment: Although if you leave it blank, it autofills something like "added X charcters in body" or "edited tags" or similar. So a whitespace summary should act the same

Comment: @Jim, if you don't insert any Edit Summary message the default message looks like this "deleted 20 chars in body" or "edited the title" or similar.

Comment: This is my first question on Meta. When do I know that bug was fixed? I wait for an official answer.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby, And YES. The code is written in Javascript. Search "Your edit" [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/post-validation.js?v=ef1f174ed861).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't leave an edit summary, you're just disrespecting the folks who'll be reviewing that edit - this amounts to shooting yourself in the foot, since if they don't understand why you're editing, they're more likely to reject the edit.

[As Linuxios notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167725/edit-with-no-edit-summary/167735#167735), it's not like we can **force** you to leave a meaningful edit summary; the length restriction is just encouragement.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is really a bug. Considering that I could just type `ssadfafasdfsedf` for my edit summary, anyone who doesn't want to give one will find a way to be able to. The length thing is mostly just to encourage giving an edit summary. Anyway, some edits are minor enough that they don't even need a summary anyway.

Comment: @Linuxious Your answer is correct seeing from this side. But then **why** did they put a chars limit? If they did this, I think that this would be nice to be fixed.

Comment: @john: I'd say as more of a suggestion to try to make people provide a description. But if someone is determined to do something enough, they can usually bypass the restriction.