# Add a tag to existing question without making a substantial edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edit-summary

I have read [Is a tag edit substantial enough?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184544/is-a-tag-edit-substantial-enough) but it is either out of date, or Stack Overflow has some added requirements.

I am trying to add a tag to a question on Stack Overflow because I feel the tag is needed and is an improvement over the generic tags on a question. When doing so, I click edit, then add the tag, but am told I can not submit my edit unless I change at least 10 characters. Is there a way to edit the tags without editing the text? The question is written fine, but the tags were written poorly.

I have about 1500 reputation on Stack Overflow in case that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10 characters are needed in the edit summary. So you need, in the edit summary section, to explain in at least 10 characters why you edited the post.

I just added a tag to your question with no problems. You need the [edit privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) in order to make these small edits without giving a summary (which I recommend you don't do). [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167725/edit-with-no-edit-summary)

Comment: To make this answer better it's worth to mention there was once a privilege gained at 500 rep, allowing users to change tags only without having this peer reviewed.

Comment: Maybe something's changed in the last 4 years. This answer isn't true anymore. If I add a tag to a question and say in the edit summary why I am doing it (size of edit summary: 77 characters), I still get a complaint "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?" pointing at the question itself.